# Chrome print blank page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

I have an old javascript code to print images, if a user clicks on the thumbnail. It used to work just fine, but lately (only in Chrome!) there is a blank page in preview.

Here is a demonstration in JsBin: http://jsbin.com/yehefuwaso/7
Click the printer icon. Now try it in Firefox; it will work as expected.

Chrome: 41.0.2272.89 m

Firefox: 30.0, 36.0.1

```
function newWindow(src){

  win = window.open("","","width=600,height=600");
    var doc = win.document;
    // init head
    var head = doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    // create title
    var title = doc.createElement("title");
    title.text = "Child Window";
    head.appendChild(title);
    // create script
    var code = "function printFunction() { window.focus(); window.print(); }";
    var script = doc.createElement("script");
    script.text = code;
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    head.appendChild(script);
    // init body
    var body = doc.body;
    //image
    doc.write('<img src="'+src+'" width="300">');

    //chrome
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1) {

      win.printFunction();               

    } else {
        win.document.close();
        win.focus();
        win.print();
        win.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's attempting to print before the `<img>` has loaded, move the call to print inside an event handler for the *load* event of `window` by opening the link as a *data URI* or *Blob*, for example

```
var code = '\
    <html>\
        <head>\
            <title></title>\
            <script>\
    function printFunction() {\
        window.focus();\
        window.print();\
        window.close();\
    }\
    window.addEventListener(\'load\', printFunction);\
            </script>\
        </head>\
        <body><img src="'+src+'" width="300"></body>\
    </html>';

window.open('data:text/html,' + code, '_blank', 'width=600,height=600');
```

---

Don't forget you may need to *HTML encode* the tags in `code`

---

You could probably just listen for *load* on the `<img>` instead, but if you ever do anything more complicated than tring to print a single image you may find it breaks again in future

```
doc.write('<img onload="printFunction();" src="'+src+'" width="300">');
```

Where `printFunction` is the print function for all browsers

Comment: I encountered a similar problem when trying to print an iframe. Calling `print()` from within `$(iframe[0].contentWindow).load()` fixes the issue.

Comment: @Paul can you help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187758/issue-while-printing-pdf-files-from-blob-agnular

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait for the image to finish loading:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = src;
img.style.width = '300px';
img.onload = function(){
  doc.write(img);
};
```

Comment: what if i have a pdf file

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem in Chrome. You can try these approaches, the first one worked for me. setTimeout didn't work for me (had to edit this later).

```
function printDiv(divName) {

    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    w = window.open();

    w.document.write(printContents);
    w.document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript">' + 'window.onload = function() { window.print(); window.close(); };' + '</sc' + 'ript>');

    w.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    w.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

    return true;
}
```

setTimeout:

```
<div id="printableArea">
      <h1>Print me</h1>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="print a div!" />



    function printDiv(divName) {

        var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        w = window.open();
        w.document.write(printContents);

        w.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        w.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

        setTimeout(function () { // necessary for Chrome
            w.print();
            w.close();
        }, 0);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: can case of pdf file what should i do?