# Issue while printing pdf files from Blob angular

Tags: javascript, angular, blob

I have an Api that returns the data in the format of

```
{ fileName: string, blob: Blob }[]
```

I want to print all these files, so I am using

```
_files.forEach((_fileInfo) => {
      const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(_fileInfo.blob);
      const oWindow = window.open(blobUrl, "print");
      oWindow.print();
      oWindow.close();
});
```

this opens the multiple print windows, but in preview it shows blank documents.

but when i download all these files as a zip it downloads the correct PDF files.

```
// add files to zip
files.forEach((_fileInfo) => {
    zip.file(_fileInfo.fileName, _fileInfo.blob);
});

// download and save
return zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then((content) => {
    if (content) {
        return saveAs(content, name);
    }
});
```

1. What could be the issue,
2. is there any way to print all documents in a sequence without opening multiple windows?

Comment: does it work properly for a single file, without a loop?

Comment: no, it shows blank document in preview

Comment: Could you specify what is `_files` collection, e.g. how do you get the value of  `_fileInfo `?

Comment: @AlenaKastsiukavets, printJs did the work, I mean now it shows the proper PDF preview, now only problem is to merge the pdf, is there any way to print multiple PDF files in single click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pdf file takes time to load thats why it was showing blank document, So i used [print-js](https://printjs.crabbly.com/) to solve this issue.

how to import

```
import * as printJS from "print-js";
```

how to use

```
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(_fileInfo.blob);
printJS(blobUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case, you don't want to use printJS

I was facing the same issue but in my case I only have to deal with one file at a time. I solved it by putting the print function in a timeout block, so in your case this would be

```
        setTimeout(function(){
            oWindow.print();
        }, 1000)
```

if this works then great, if not then you might also need to set the source of window equal to the 'blobUrl' that you created. This should be done after you come out of the loop.